# Marklogic 9 MLCP ingest from URL does not work

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, mlcp

I am using Marklogic 9 and want to ingest data from a website (url), which delivers me a JSON string as result.

I try this with MarkLogic Content Pump (MLCP) with the following statement:

```
mlcp.sh import -mode local -host localhost -port 8000 -username admin -password admin -input_file_path https://services7.arcgis.com/21GdwfcLrnTpiju8/arcgis/rest/services/Geluidsbelasting/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json
```

I receive the following message after executing the "MLCP" statement:

```
[1] 124877
[2] 124878
[3] 124879
[2]-  Done
```

When I check with the Query Console the **documents** show no new records.

Can you please tel me what must change to let this work

Many thanks

Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MLCP doesn't support loading data from a remote service. You could download the data and then use `-input_file_path` to point to where you downloaded it.